# Why return object in invoke method of MethodInterceptor interface?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I just started on the chapter about AOP in Pro Spring 2.5. In the interface `MethodInterceptor` you implement the invoke method. Why does this method return an instance of Object?

Comment: What do you think it should return?

Answer (score 0):

```
Caller -> Interceptor -> Real object
```

The caller expects the invocation to return an object as a result (unless it is void). That's why the interceptor has to return an object. Note that this is true for all similar proxy mechanisms.

If the intercepted method has a `void` return type, you can return `null` from the interceptor. If you need any parametrization - use `<Void>`

Comment: The method it intercepts is void.

Comment: I think the thing is it has to deal with the case when you might want to return something - in your case you don't, so you could just return a dummy object I think